# WorkflowApplication Resume Workflow with dynamic DLLs

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, workflow-foundation-4

I have a web application that generates custom DLLs on the runtime. 
We need a mechanism to run workflows on types defined in these runtime created DLLs.
The system gives out a byte array of the generated DLL and we do a

Assembly.Load(byteArray[])

The types defined in this DLL are available in the web application layer. 
But when I try to resume a workflow by doing a

WorkflowApplication.Load(WFInstanceId)

It results in an exception where the exception says :

Cannot load the assembly "MyNamespace1.MyDll1"

Is there a way, I can use my applications AppDomain in the workflows ?

Comment: This approach on MSDN works but looks like it will work only for rehosted designers etc.  http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/ab83f4a6-8dc0-4bd9-9617-1e1622ce5ba5/running-workflow-with-custom-assembly-resolver